# Como executar um script externo a partir de um formulário do WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, formulário

Eu acabei de instalar a última versao do WordPress e criei uma página com um formulário simples.

```
<form class="" method="post" action="insert.php">
    <input name="name" placeholder="Name">
    <input name="email" placeholder="E-Mail">
    <input name="company" placeholder="Company">
    <button name="submit" type="submit">OK</button>
</form>
```

Eu gostaria entao de inserir os dados desse formulário em uma tabela do banco de dados. Pesquisei e descobri que um possível código para fazer isso seria:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        global $wpdb;

        $wpdb->insert
            ('users', // Nome da tabela no banco de dados.
                array
                (
                    'name'=>$_POST['name'],
                    'email'=>$_POST['email'],
                    'company'=>$_POST['company'],
                    'registration'=>now()]
                )
            );

        echo 'Usuário inserido com sucesso!'
    }
?>
```

As perguntas seriam:

Eu devo inserir esse código logo abaixo do código do formulário ou salvar tudo em um arquivo externo?

E se esse for o caso, onde eu devo salvar o arquivo insert.php para que ele seja rodado ao se clicar no botao de submit?

Comment: Se quiser deixe tudo no mesmo arquivo do form, só deixe a `action=""` vazia para que ao submeter o form retorne para a própria página e rode a condição `if(isset($_POST['submit'])`

Comment: @ThyagoThySofT obrigado por sua resposta, mas infelizmente nao funcionou... O código do PHP aparece logo abaixo do formulário...

Comment: Não funcionou significa que deu algum erro ou simplesmente não realizou o insert? Se deu algum erro, relate o erro.

Comment: Se o código PHP aparece logo abaixo como texto vendo no navegador, provavelmente é algo do WP. Sei que se for inserir PHP pelo painel Admin em uma determinada página, se não me engano, precisa de plugin para isso, pois o WP escapa as tags e variáveis, apresentando como texto simples. Caso seja isso, medida alternativa é abrir o próprio arquivo PHP via FTP e colocar este script.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode deixar esse código no mesmo arquivo ou em um arquivo separado. Aconselho deixar em um arquivo separado a logica que esta dentro do `if`, depois é só você dar um `include` do arquivo dentro do seu `if` verificando o `post`. 
Exemplo:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    include('meuArquivo.php');
}
```

E dentro do `meuArquivo.php`

```
global $wpdb;

$wpdb->insert
  ('users', // Nome da tabela no banco de dados.
    array
    (
      'name'=>$_POST['name'],
      'email'=>$_POST['email'],
      'company'=>$_POST['company'],
      'registration'=>now()]
    )
  );
echo 'Usuário inserido com sucesso!'
```